# The preview of markdown has issue when italic nested in bold?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

When I make italic nested in bold as head or tail in bold block, there will be "**" at tail of preview.
Does it a preview problem, or Can't write like this in markdown?

Markdown Code as bellow:

```
<!-- No Problem. -->
**There is *italic* nested *in* bold.**  
<!-- Has Problem. -->
**There is *italic* nested in bold*.***  
***There* is*italic* nested in bold.**
```

[Click here to see the capture of issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NetcH.png)

Thanks very much.

Comment: I don't use Visual Studio Code, but can you try... just separate them with a space? Can `_..._` be used instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replicate your code in [this](https://dillinger.io/) editor and it gives me same issue.

You can write it like this:

```
**There is *italic* nested in *bold.*** (Tail)
***There* is italic nested in bold.** (Head)
```

and it will do the work!

[image]

Comment: In conclusion, that's a bug with Visual studio code.

Comment: Nope. I modified the original version.

Comment: Note that I'm not the OP. The OP's username is highlighed with blue background in the comment section.

Comment: Right, I modified the comment :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You use another editor, but has same issue... So it might be a issue of protocal of MarkDown?

Comment: Yes, I think it is.